# Mediaelement player controls scrambled

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have multiple `<video>` elements dynamically hidden and shown through jQuery scripts. This works fine except the video controls are positioned all to the left and over each other instead of the standard layout.

When I manage to hit the full screen widget and have it revert back to embedded, suddenly the controls are fine.

Page is built with html5 boilerplate with scripts in the header.

My guess is that mediaelement gets confused or not updated properly by the dynamic loading, which the full screen operation fixes?

Comment: I need to switch from audio player to video player so I'm hiding each one alternatively.
So I have controls scrambled too. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of showing and hidding `<video>` containing divs, this
[Switch-Video-Example](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/wiki/Switch-Video-Example) directly switches the src.